# Non-logged table load without using SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently to load into our report tables first we drop then create using select fields into rptTable

Example:

```
DROP dbo.rptTable
SELECT fields
INTO dbo.rptTable
```

This is done to have a non-logged table load.

Is there a way to do this without the drop/create using into?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking to avoid logging for performance reasons?

Comment: No. SQL server is always logging to the transaction log. That's just how it is designed to work. Even if you set your recovery mode to simple it still logs. If the inserts are a performance hit you could always drop the indexes from the table before inserting.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, in an earlier comment I stated that this was solely for performance, the primary reason actually is to prevent the transaction log from filling up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
truncate table rptTable
insert into rptTable with (TABLOCK)
select fields 
from source
```

See "Best Practices for Bulk Importing Data" at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=sql.105).aspx